# Changing webpack digest method

Tags: webpack, digest

The server I am trying to build on does not have `md4`/`md5` available (can't change this). Is there a way to force Webpack and all of the plugins to use a specific digest method? In my `webpack.[env].config` I have:

```
...
output: {
    hashFunction: "RSA-SHA1"
}
...
```

I can build the project with this change locally, and I can run `crypto.createHash('RSA-SHA1')` on the remote server, but trying to run Webpack with the updated config on the remote server still results in `crypto.js` spitting out:

```
Error: Digest method not supported
```

All the plugins I'm using source the `hashfunction` from `output`, so it doesn't seem to be an issue with that. Any thoughts on how to resolve this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you create a hash using that function on the remote server?

Comment: What's the stack trace of the error?

Comment: @PlayMa256 yes. i mentioned that in the second paragraph.

Comment: sorry, i missread that.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem...